# Checkbox with a ObjectListField not focusable and checkable?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am trying to create a checkbox and below this objectlist is there. I am trying to focus on checkbox but it is niether focusable nor checkable .The focus stands on the first element of the list below.

How I can focus the checkbox as well as making it checkable? Here, checkbox is in a VerticalFieldManager in which I am adding the list.

[image]

Here I am adding two things:one is Horizontal Field Manager(onlineCheckBoxHfm) and other is objectListField(buddyList).

Now problem is, default focus is on first element of the list and I am unable to get focus on HorizontalFieldManager in which I have put the CheckBox. Since focus is not available on HorizontalFieldManager so I am unable to check the CheckBox.

```java
public class BuddyMenuItem extends VerticalFieldManager implements FieldChangeListener{   

 public BuddyMenuItem(BuddyListField buddyList) {

        _bitmap = EncodedImage.
        getEncodedImageResource("buddies_header.png");
        mainMenuBmp = new BitmapField(Constant.sizePic(_bitmap, _bitmap.getHeight(), Display.getWidth()));

        HorizontalFieldManager onlineCheckBoxHfm=new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        _onlineCheckBox=new CheckboxField("Online",false,CheckboxField.FIELD_LEFT|CheckboxField.FOCUSABLE);
        _onlineCheckBox.setChangeListener(this);

        onlineCheckBoxHfm.add(_onlineCheckBox);
        onlineCheckBoxHfm.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));
//      add(mainMenuBmp);
        add(onlineCheckBoxHfm);
        add(buddyList);
    }
```

BuddyListField class is as follows:

```java
import java.util.Vector;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Touchscreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectListField;

import com.np.naijapings.Buddy;
import com.np.naijapings.NaijapingsMain;

public class BuddyListField extends ObjectListField {
    public static final Bitmap offlineIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("offline.png");
    public static final Bitmap awayIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("away.png");
    public static final Bitmap busyIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("busy.png");
    public static final Bitmap onlineIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("online.png");
    public static final Bitmap unreadIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("unread.png");
    public static final Bitmap maleIcon=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("male.png");

    public static final Bitmap[] statusIcon = new Bitmap[]{offlineIcon, awayIcon, busyIcon, onlineIcon};

    public static Vector buddyVector;
    public static int onlineBuddyCount=0;
    private final NPingsMain nPings;
    public static boolean showOnlineBuddy=false;

    private Bitmap _chatBmp=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("chat.png");

    public BuddyListField(NPingsMain n,boolean showOnlineBuddy) {
        nPings = n;
        buddyVector = new Vector();
        this.showOnlineBuddy=showOnlineBuddy;
    }

    public Buddy getBuddyAt(int index) {
        return (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(index);     
    }

    protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
        int idx;
        switch(key) {
        case Keypad.KEY_ENTER:
            idx = this.getSelectedIndex();
            if (idx >= 0) {
                NPingsMain.currentBuddy = (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(idx);
                NPingsMain.openBuddy(NPingsMain.currentBuddy);
            }
            return true;

        case 'e':
            idx = this.getSelectedIndex()-1;
            if (idx >= 0) {
                this.setSelectedIndex(idx);
            }
            return true;

        case 's':
            return true;

        case 'f':
            return true;

        case 'x':
            idx = this.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            if (idx > 0 && idx < this.getSize()) {
                this.setSelectedIndex(idx);
            }
            return true;

        case 't':
            if (this.getSize() > 0) {
                this.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        int idx = this.getSelectedIndex();
        if(Touchscreen.isSupported()){
            if (idx >= 0) {
                nPings.currentBuddy = (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(idx);
                if((nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000003)||(nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000002)||(nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000001)){
                    NPingsMain.openBuddy(nPings.currentBuddy);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }else{

            if (idx >= 0) {
                nPings.currentBuddy = (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(idx);
                if((nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000003)||(nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000002)||(nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000001)){
                    NPingsMain.openBuddy(nPings.currentBuddy);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        //if(message.getEvent()==TouchEvent.CLICK){
            int idx;
            switch(TouchEvent.CLICK) {
            case TouchEvent.CLICK:
                idx = this.getSelectedIndex();
                if (idx >= 0) {
                    nPings.currentBuddy = (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(idx);
                    if((nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000003)||(nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000002)||(nPings.currentBuddy.status==0x00000001)){
                        NPingsMain.openBuddy(nPings.currentBuddy);
                    }
                }
                return true;

            case 'e':
                idx = this.getSelectedIndex()-1;
                if (idx >= 0) {
                    this.setSelectedIndex(idx);
                }
                return true;

            case 's':
                return true;

            case 'f':
                return true;

            case 'x':
                idx = this.getSelectedIndex()+1;
                if (idx > 0 && idx < this.getSize()) {
                    this.setSelectedIndex(idx);
                }
                return true;

            case 't':
                if (this.getSize() > 0) {
                    this.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
                return true;
            }

        //  return false;

    //  }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }

    public void buddyReposition(Buddy b) {
        int index = buddyVector.indexOf(b);
        buddyReposition(index);
    }

    public void buddyReposition(int oldIndex) {
        Buddy b = (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(oldIndex);
        int newIndex = 0;

        if (b.unread) {
            newIndex = 0;
        } else {
            while (newIndex < buddyVector.size() &&
                    ((b == (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(newIndex)) || 
                            ((Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(newIndex)).unread || 
                            (b.status < ((Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(newIndex)).status)))
                ++newIndex;
        }

        newIndex = (oldIndex < newIndex) ? (newIndex-1) : newIndex;

        if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
            buddyVector.removeElementAt(oldIndex);
            buddyVector.insertElementAt(b, newIndex);
        }

        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int findBuddyIndex(String jid) {
        for (int i = buddyVector.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (((Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(i)).jid.equals(jid))
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Buddy findBuddy(String jid) {
        for (int i = buddyVector.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (((Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(i)).jid.equals(jid))
                return (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addBuddy(Buddy b) {
        //CHECK FOR ONLINE BUDDIES  
        buddyVector.addElement(b);
        this.insert(buddyVector.indexOf(b));

    }

    public void deleteBuddy(int index){
        buddyVector.removeElementAt(index);
        this.delete(index);

    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) {
        // NOTICE 14 would be consist the icon size

        onlineBuddyCount=0; 
        String bName="";
        Buddy b = (Buddy)buddyVector.elementAt(index);
        if(showOnlineBuddy==true){
            if(b.status==0x00000003||b.status==0x00000002||b.status==0x00000001){

                //DRAW ROW BACKGROUND START
                if (listField.getSelectedIndex() != index) {
                    graphics.setBackgroundColor(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE
                            : Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                    graphics.clear();
                    listField.setFocus();
                }
                //DRAW ROW BACKGROUND END

                onlineBuddyCount++;
                if(b.name.endsWith("net")){
                    int i=b.name.indexOf("@");
                    bName=b.name.substring(0, i);
                }else{
                    bName=b.name;
                }
                if (b.unread) {
                    graphics.drawBitmap(0, y+3, unreadIcon.getWidth(), unreadIcon.getHeight(),unreadIcon , 0, 0);
                } else {
                    graphics.drawBitmap(0, y+3, unreadIcon.getWidth(), unreadIcon.getHeight(),statusIcon[b.status] , 0, 0);
                }

                graphics.drawText(bName, 25, y, DrawStyle.HDEFAULT, width-12);
                graphics.drawBitmap(Display.getWidth()-_chatBmp.getWidth(), y-6, _chatBmp.getWidth(), _chatBmp.getHeight(), _chatBmp, 0, 0);
            }
        }else{
            //DRAW ROW BACKGROUND START
            if (listField.getSelectedIndex() != index) {
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE
                        : Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                graphics.clear();
                listField.setFocus();
            }
            //DRAW ROW BACKGROUND END

            onlineBuddyCount++;
            if(b.name.endsWith("net")){
                int i=b.name.indexOf("@");
                bName=b.name.substring(0, i);
            }else{
                bName=b.name;
            }
            if (b.unread) {
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y+3, unreadIcon.getWidth(), unreadIcon.getHeight(),unreadIcon , 0, 0);
            } else {
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y+3, unreadIcon.getWidth(), unreadIcon.getHeight(),statusIcon[b.status] , 0, 0);
            }

            graphics.drawText(bName, 25, y, DrawStyle.HDEFAULT, width-12);
            graphics.drawBitmap(Display.getWidth()-_chatBmp.getWidth(), y-6, _chatBmp.getWidth(), _chatBmp.getHeight(), _chatBmp, 0, 0);
        }
    }



    public void clearBuddies() {
        if (nPings.buddyList != null) {
            int i = buddyVector.size();
            while (i-- > 0)
                this.delete(0);
            nPings.buddyscreen.delete(nPings.buddyList);
            nPings.buddyList = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to create your CheckBoxField and add it to a Manager (with the ObjectListField) and then the Screen.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's anything in the code you show.  If `BuddyListField` is just an `ObjectListField`, then I am able to focus and check the checkbox.  Maybe you can post the `BuddyListField` class, and also tell us what class `BuddyMenuItem` *extends*?

Comment: @Nate:I have updated the code ,with BuddyListField class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your code, because there's too much in there that I don't have (other classes, PNGs, etc.), but I would be willing to bet that your problem is here:

```java
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) {

   // other stuff here

      listField.setFocus();
```

Calling `setFocus()` will set the focus on the list field (the `BuddyListField`).  So, your `CheckBoxField` **is** actually focusable.  The problem is that you add the checkbox field, and then add the listfield.  When the listfield is drawn, with `drawListRow()`, you are always taking focus away from the checkbox and putting it back on the listfield.

Remove that call to `listField.setFocus()` ... there are two of them.

`drawListRow()` is meant for drawing.  I'm not sure I can think of a reason why anything in that method should actually **change** the focus, which is what `setFocus()` does.

Comment: Thanks Nate.It was just because of **setFocus()** method ,checkbox was not getting focus.I removed the focus from there and now its working.